# Compare comma-separated string in MySQL column where column is also comma separated

Tags: mysql

Compare comma-separated string in MySQL column where column is also comma separated

For Example:

```
Id name catid
1  abc   4,5,2
2  bcd   5
3  efg   9,1,7

SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE catid IN (2,5,6)
```

Here 2,5,6 I have to compare with the catid value to get the result.
Any Help to get the right out put, I used FIND_IN_SET, but could not make it work for my case

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in a single column. The fact that this query is a problem now is a direct result of the wrong database design

Comment: @Ozone which is data type of catid ?

Comment: @ChintanGor varchar 255. in which the value is stored as 1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

according to your problem you can use LIKE operator instead of IN

```
SELECT * FROM testchintan  WHERE CONCAT(',',catid,',') LIKE '%,5,%'
OR CONCAT(',',catid,',') LIKE '%,2,%' OR CONCAT(',',catid,',') LIKE '%,6,%'
```

OR YOU can use REGEXP

```
SELECT *
  FROM testchintan
 WHERE catid REGEXP '[4,9,5]'
```

OR

```
SELECT *
  FROM testchintan
 WHERE 
 REPLACE(catid,',','|') REGEXP '[9,7]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that I'm not seriously advocating this as a solution...

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(5,catid) OR FIND_IN_SET(2,catid);
```